Can you solve this math problem? ~ It/That looks difficult

Mary: Can you solve this math problem?
Susan: It/That looks difficult.

Which should I use, It or That?
I am confused because "it" and "that" both correspond to the same Japanese pronoun sore.

This and that are used if you're pointing to something or otherwise indicating it. What is Susan doing?

@StuartF Thank you, Stuart F. Mary and Susan are sitting next to each other at a table talking about their math homework.

Both are technically correct, but It looks difficult sounds more natural to me as an immediate response to a direct question in a conversation.
As a side note, if you wanted to use this or that instead of it, I recommend "this" (kore) to match "this" (kono) math problem.

Thank you, automaton. Can I use It, regardless of the distance between Mary and Susan?

Correct! "It" does not imply any kind of distance. Most pronouns do not. This, that, these, and those are specifically called demonstrative adjectives (when used in the "kono" sense), or demonstrative pronouns (when used in the "kore" sense), and often imply a distance. Him, her, it, they, or similar pronouns have nothing to do with distance.

"That" can express a degree of disengagement, not just relative physical distance.
"looks difficult"  suggests the speaker hasn't studied  the problem but is judging its difficulty by the "gestalt" of the problem as represented on the page.
"That" reinforces the notion that the speaker is not fully engaged in trying to solve the problem, has not yet "dived into" the problem. They are not yet studying it and considering it carefully.
"It" is neutral and neither reinforces nor weakens the effect of "looks difficult".
